# are the results of echo $(FOO=bar foobar) unspecified in a POSIX shell?

Tags: shell, posix

I am trying to understand the POSIX shell standard [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04)

From reading it, appears to me in the following shell command:

```
echo $(FOO=bar foobar)
```

there are two tokens (for the top level shell, not the subshell):  `echo` and `$(FOO=bar foobar)`

This is a useful type of command and not contrived at all, so it should be defined what the results are.  But when you try to parse it using the grammar given in the standard, the second token is unspecified by Rule 7b of the grammar - because it contains `=` but before that, is not a valid name.

Are the results of such a "normal" command really not specified?  Or what am not understanding??

Comment: `7b` only applies to words before the first WORD. Here, the first WORD is `echo`. The question would still stand for `$(foo=bar; echo echo) bar`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I respectfully disagree - from the grammar, clearly, 7b applies to words _after_ the first one (there is nothing before the first one, by definition).

Comment: That's about _Assignment preceding command name_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  yes I know :)  that label is misleading and should be disregarded - note that this rule applies, from the productions for `cmd_word` and `cmd_name` to command name itself, and in the rule itself, also talks about command names.

Comment: I agree it's unclear. I would suggest you ask those questions on the [austin group mailing list](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/lists.html). (that list relied on gmane for the archives, I'm not sure where to find them now that gmane web interface is gone).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think I found the new mailing list: austin-group-l@opengroup.org  thank you for this pointer!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes austin-group-l@opengroup.org, as in the link I gave has been the ML all along. It's just that it's now difficult to search the archives on the web (they've started to use mail-archive.com, but there's only a few days worth of archive).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `echo $(FOO=bar foobar)` has two tokens: `echo` and `$(FOO=bar foobar)`.

The first token is a command, the second one is an expansion `$(…)`.

The command is recognized in [step 1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03)

The expansion is recognized in [step 5](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03)

> If the current character is an unquoted '$' or '`', the shell shall identify the start of any candidates for parameter expansion (Parameter Expansion), command substitution (Command Substitution) …

A "[Command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)" to be more precise:

> … Command substitution shall occur when the command is enclosed as follows:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing *command* in a subshell environment and **replacing the command substitution (the text of *command* plus the enclosing "$()" or backquotes) with the standard output of the *command*** …
>
> With the $(*command*) form, all characters following the open parenthesis to the matching closing parenthesis constitute the *command*.

It is therefore clear that the *command* to be executed in a sub-shell would be:

```
FOO=bar foobar
```

Which also has two tokens: a variable assignment (`FOO=bar`) and a command (`foobar`).

The result of executing such *command* will replace the whole `$(…)`.

That is all valid POSIX syntax, I fail to see any issue.

Comment: you don't understand my question.  I am not at all asking how this works, which you spend the whole answer explaining.  I know this, you don't have to explain.  There is one bit in your answer that relates to my question:  you are saying this is valid POSIX.  How is it valid, this is my question - how is the grammar accepting the second token `$(FOO=bar foobar).  Just tell me precisely how does it do that?

Comment: You don't have to be patronizing.  Never mind.  I just found out, from the POSIX Standard Group, this is a known issue and they have approved a fix, but has not been published yet.  Have  a nice day.